# Not able to figure out why printf printing different on standard output

Tags: c

Trying to understand the behaviour of union

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct abc{
        unsigned long a;
        unsigned long b;
//      unsigned long c;
};

union temp
{
        struct abc a;
        unsigned long arr[2048];
};

int main()
{
        union temp temp;
        temp.a.a = 3;
        temp.a.b = 'a';
//      temp.a.c = 2;
        printf("add : 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x \n", temp.a.a, temp.a.b, temp.arr[0]);
        printf("add : 0x%x 0x%x \n",temp.a,temp.arr[0]);
        return 0;
}

Output:
add : 0x3 0x61 0x3 
add : 0x3 0x61
```

Question: why in second printf variable "temp.arr[0]" is printing 0x61 while it should print again 0x3?

Comment: Using `"%x"` to print a `unsigned long` is undefined behavior.  Use matching specifiers and arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In your second `printf` you have 
`temp.a` which is not what you want.
If you change it to `temp.a.a` it will work as expected.

Comment: I agree with u. Even if I interchange the sequence of variable to print it will print as i am expecting but question remain there why it is happening like this.

Comment: @user3891247 - It looks like undefined behavior to me - `%x` is expecting an unsigned integer and you are passing it a `struct` instead when you put `temp.a` rather than `temp.a.a`

Answer (score 1):

What does the program do at the second printf ?

```
    printf("add : 0x%x 0x%x \n",temp.a,temp.arr[0]);
```

First the arguments are pushed on the stack. Apparently the first argument to be pushed is temp.arr[0], then temp.a is pushed. So your stack will contain the entire temp.a variable ie : 3,'a' followed by temp.arr[0]. Printf looks at the format string and as asked to print an integer pops the first 3, when asked to pop another int it pops the 'a'=0x61.

To get the right output simply give `temp.a.a` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time.

In union you have to store in any data member and then access it using same data member. If you want to access from different data member then store it before accessing using that member. See the example below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union Data {
   int i;
   float f;
   char str[20];
};

int main( ) {

   union Data data;        

   data.i = 10;
   printf( "data.i : %d\n", data.i);

   data.f = 220.5;
   printf( "data.f : %f\n", data.f);

   strcpy( data.str, "C Programming");
   printf( "data.str : %s\n", data.str);

   return 0;
}
```

Ans would be

```
data.i : 10
data.f : 220.500000
data.str : C Programming
```

Comment: In my code snippet , printf is printing different value for temp.arr[0]. As per my understanding in both case it should print 0x3

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm
Give it a read, and it will clear your each problem about union. Moreover if you still have problem post your full code.

Comment: Thats because you are trying to print  struct abc not its member a. If you will correct it, it will show the right output. Moreover this is not the standard practice to do so. The answer in union in your case is same just because you are using almost same type i.e. both are unsigned long.

Answer (score 0):

In the below line first two format specifiers were consumed by the temp.a.a and temp.a.b because you are passing the whole structure variable not an individual member.

```
 printf("add : 0x%x 0x%x \n",temp.a,temp.arr[0]);
```

So there is no format specifier left for temp.arr[0] to print its value to console. You should provide a third format specifier or change the temp.a to temp.a.a

```
 printf("add : 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x \n",temp.a,temp.arr[0]);
```

This will print the same output as the first print statement. i.e.
add : 0x3 0x61 0x3